# Kafka API Encoder vs Serializer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am just starting learning Kafka and wondering what is the difference between **Encoder** and **Serializer**. It seems to me that they are doing the same thing but I am trying to find out which API is newer, unfortunately with no luck. The other thing which makes me confused is what is the difference between **kafka.javaapi.Producer** and **KafkaProducer**?

Comment: For new API, please read Confluent docs about Kafka: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/clients/index.html

Answer (score 1):

`Serializer` is the newer Class.
`KafkaProducer` is a producer written in `scala` and `kafka.javaapi.Producer` is a java wrapper over the `scala` class.